# add new page to existing website without modifying the rest of the website

Tags: asp.net

i have to add one page to an existing asp.net webforms website.

this will be added at runtime and i'm not allowed to redeploy the entire webapplication / website.

is the (recommended or only) solution to move the code behind code to the aspx file, or do i have other options?

i can't put code in the dll's, and dynamicly runned .cs files are only in the case of a website and not in the case of a webapplication, am i right?

and putting the code from my code behind in de aspx file will always work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually as long as their page link to yours via URL you web page doesn't necessary have to be in the same project, unless you're trying to reuse something.

Else technically your project is fine as a standalone and they can just link to yours.
Unless you're worried about the URL then you would have to either use an iframe or some other URL rewrite.

Comment: so i can build an entire new website and redirect the url www.example.com/mypart to my website (which is an entire new website with my own app pool, web.config etc.?)

Comment: Yup, the only reason why it has to be in the same site is to maintain the same URL structure or to reuse stuff, since you pretty much cannot touch their site, then there's no reason to build within the same structure. Also note that u might want to consider stuff like Session, authentication, cookies, etc from the original site to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference: One solution would be to use a dynamic proxy and intercept and extend the existing webapp. Though this approach might be a little too involved for what you're trying to achieve.

[LinFu](https://github.com/philiplaureano/LinFu)
[Castle](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html)